# Make file accessible to one program only on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I have a sensitive file in my computer and I wanted to configure Windows to give only one program access to this file.

In Linux this is straightforward, you create a new user, a new group for the user, configure its shell and login and then in a second you have your program and file under the same user and group nicely under their sandbox.

**Is it possible to make this in Windows as well?**

I want to avoid a worst case scenario where a virus could sniff my computer and copy/read this file somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know much about Linux, but I'm guessing that if you're root you can get around the permissions you describe and gain access to that file. In any case, if one (including malware) gets administrator permissions on Windows, you can circumvent any permissions put in place. Will this be ok for your scenario?

Comment: Well, the same problem happens on Linux, security is about layers of protection, not total protection

Comment: Yes, I understand and agree. So do you want to know how to give only a single Windows user access to a file as per your analogous Linux scenario? Or more than that? (If it makes a difference, you don't assign permissions in Windows to programs, only users or groups).

Comment: I have an SSH key file and I don't want other programs to be able to copy this file, so I wanted some way to lock it, so only my SSH client program could read this file....in Linux this is easy, just make the file and the program on the same `group` and maybe `user` and restrict `others` access...but on windows I don't even know if this is possible

Comment: So in Windows you grant permissions to *identities* (primarily users, and groups) that run programs, not programs themselves. However, every program must run in the context of *some* identity, so if you set the permissions to your file to only allow a specific user, one that you don't use to run untrusted programs, you'll prevent other programs from accessing the file.

Comment: But will I have to logout of my regular account and then login with that user in order to use my file?

Comment: Nope. You just need to run the program using the designated user account. You do this by right-clicking the program (or shortcut) and choose Run As. No need to logout.

Comment: Now you've got me thinking about this. I wonder if it would make sense to also/instead encrypt the file until you need to use it. That would be much more secure, even eliminating the threat of malicious code that gains administrative rights.

Comment: Yeah, I already have it encrypted, it's just I also need a second copy which is unencrypted, and besides I am using Veracrypt which means whenever I need to use the unencrypted file it becomes open to the whole computer to see

Comment: So this is more to circumvent veracrypt "openness"